# How to Sort By Frequency And Then Filter Repeats in JavaScript - Solution

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I got one question during an interview.
The question was to sort the array based on repeat char count.

**Question** :

```
['#','$','#','?','?','#','#','#']
```

**Output** :

```
[#,#,#,#,#,?,?,$]
```

So I tried to write a solution and it is working as expected.
Please see my solution in the comment and let me know if there is a scope of optimization available.

Please let me know if any suggestions or concerns

Comment: Actually, this belongs on codereview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, how about

```js
q = ['#','$','#','?','?','#','#','#']

a = q
    .sort()
    .join('')
    .match(/(.)\1*/g)
    .sort((x, y) => y.length - x.length)
    .join('')
    .split('')

console.log(...a)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could take a single loop for counting the occurences and then sort by their frequency.

```js
const
    values = ['#', '$', '#', '?', '?', '#', '#', '#'],
    counts = values.reduce((r, v) => (r[v] = (r[v] || 0) + 1, r), {});

values.sort((a, b) => counts[b] - counts[a]);

console.log(...values);
```

Comment: Thanks it is working as expected. But i did not use google for this answer please check below my answer if there is any scope of optimization. Please let me know. @Nina Scholz

Comment: what do you mean with *"scope optimization"*? even the question lacks the information if the array should keep the same object reference. your approach does not hand over an array to the function and it does not return any array or if mutating, keeps the reference to the array.

Comment: Note to OP, the reduce method invocation is a good way to approach problems that require a counting mechanism. Very nice use of conditional expression too.

Comment: Thanks @NinaScholz. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Question : ['#','$','#','?','?','#','#','#']
Output : [#,#,#,#,#,?,?,$]

```
function ArrayLearning()
{
  var x = ['#','$','#','?','?','#','#','#']; 
  var j = []; 
  var sorted = [];
  var t = "";

  x.forEach(ele => 
  { 
       if(sorted.indexOf(ele) < 0) 
       {
         var length = x.filter(s => s == ele).length;
         j.push(ele+"-" + length); 
       }

       sorted.push(ele);
  });
  
  j.sort(function(a,b) {  return b.split("-")[1] - a.split("-")[1]; });
  
  x = [];

  j.forEach(ele => { 
       var currentKeyAndValue = ele.split("-");

       for(var te = 0; te < currentKeyAndValue[1]; te++)
       {
           x.push(currentKeyAndValue[0]);
       } 
  });

  return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `Array.prototype.filter() and Array.prototype.sort()`.

```js
const values = ["#", "$", "#", "?", "?", "#", "#", "#"],
  compute = item => values.filter(el => el === item).length,
  solution = values.slice().sort((a, b) => compute(b) - compute(a));

console.log(solution);
```